# matlab complex numbers representation

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

based on what I can document myself if I want to represent a complex number in  matlab, also I carry the chart that I get, with the blue line the result obtained and the red line the desired result :

```
z=2+3i; 
compass(z);
```

[image: polar]
or

```
z=2+3i; 
quiver(0,0,real(z),imag(z));
```

[image]

I do not know if it is my conceptual problem in the representation of real and imaginary parts.

my goal is to get something so similar: [img1 wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Complex_number_illustration.svg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't let quiver auto scale your arrows!

```
quiver(0,0,real(z),imag(z),1); % Scale=1
```

The first plot is OK, the modulus of your number is `sqrt(2^2+3^2) ~~ 3.6`